# Is there a way to manage the column/cell widths when exporting to Excel with django-import-export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I don't see anything about it in the docs for django-import-export. I would like to know if there is a way to change the width of columns in the exported Excel spreadsheet, so that the column becomes wide enough to fit all data? (Right now it is splitting a long piece of data between two narrow columns.) Perhaps something in the resource customization?