# django-import-export How to format the exported excel's cell?

Tags: django, excel, django-import-export

Is there any way I can format the exported excel file? When i export the files, the column is too small to fit the words. Im quite new to this so any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Exported excel file looks something like this, the title cell is too small to fit the words.]

If django-import-export is unable to do this, then is there any other methods to export database information as excel and is able to format the files?

There's actually someone who asked a similar question but there's no answer:

[Is there a way to manage the column/cell widths when exporting to Excel with django-import-export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639271/is-there-a-way-to-manage-the-column-cell-widths-when-exporting-to-excel-with-dja)

Some of my code in admin.py

```
class LogResource(resources.ModelResource):
    date = Field(attribute='date', column_name='Date')
    dtime = Field(attribute='dtime', column_name='Departure Time')
    pilot = Field(attribute='pilot', column_name='Pilot')
    cpilot = Field(attribute='cpilot', column_name='Co-Pilot')
    purpose = Field(attribute='purpose', column_name='Purpose of Flight')
    others = Field(attribute='others', column_name='Others')

    class Meta:
        model=Log
        exclude=('id',)


class LogAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = LogResource
    list_display = ('date', 'dtime', 'purpose', 'pilot', 'cpilot')
    list_filter = ('date', 'purpose', 'pilot')
```

In views.py

```
def logentry_form_submission(request):
    date = request.POST["date"]
    dtime = request.POST["dtime"]
    pilot = request.POST["pilot"]
    cpilot = request.POST["cpilot"]
    purpose = request.POST["purpose"]
    others = request.POST["others"]

    log_info = Log(date=date, dtime=dtime, pilot=pilot, cpilot=cpilot,         
    purpose=purpose, others=others)
    log_info.save()
    return render(request, 'myhtml/logentry_form_submission.html')
```

My code is abit messy since I learn everything online so feel free to improve my code.

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/500) but it doesn't seem to have much traction.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way. I was able to workaround it by:

- registering own tablib format
- defining formatting per Resource
- passing formatter callback from resource class to tablib export code

Register your own tablib format:

```
from tablib.formats import registry
from tablib.formats._xlsx import XLSXFormat
class FormattedXLSX(XLSXFormat):
    @classmethod
    def export_set(cls, dataset, freeze_panes=True, formatter=None):
        """Returns XLSX representation of Dataset."""
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        ws.title = dataset.title if dataset.title else "Tablib Dataset"

        cls.dset_sheet(dataset, ws, freeze_panes=freeze_panes)

        ### Just added this lines to original code
        if formatter:
            formatter(ws)
        ###

        stream = BytesIO()
        wb.save(stream)
        return stream.getvalue()


registry.register("xlsx", FormattedXLSX())
```

Adjust columns widths in resource class:

```
class OrderResource(resources.ModelResource):
    @staticmethod
    def formatter(ws):
        ws.column_dimensions["B"].width = 15
        ws.column_dimensions["C"].width = 35
        ws.column_dimensions["D"].width = 12
        ws.column_dimensions["F"].width = 18

    class Meta:
        model = OrderFull
```

Now we need to pass it somehow to tablib. Take a look at source:
https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/2.0.2/import_export/admin.py#L461
You can override this method, and change `export_data = file_format.export_data(data)` to `export_data = file_format.export_data(data, resource_class.formatter)` (Didn't tested it).

Since I'm using it different way (without admin integration) I can provide a bit different implementation, but inspired by original ExportMixin code.

```
class ImportExportView(APIView):
    # ...
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        dataset = self.resource().export(self.queryset.all())
        # Inject formatter function from resource
        xslx = XLSX().export_data(dataset=dataset, formatter=self.resource.formatter)

        response = HttpResponse(
            content=xslx,
            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        )
        response["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename="{self.filename}"'
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

So for that, you have to make your own Tablib Format.

_prettyxlsx.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from tablib.formats._xlsx import XLSXFormat



class PrettyXLSXFormat(XLSXFormat):
    @classmethod
    def export_set(cls, dataset, freeze_panes=True, invalid_char_subst="-"):
        """Returns XLSX representation of Dataset."""

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        ws.title = dataset.title if dataset.title else "Dataset"

        cls.dset_sheet(dataset, ws, freeze_panes=freeze_panes)

        # ---------DO YOUR FORMATTING HERE FOR EXAMPLE------------

        # Set the row dimensions
        for row in ws.rows:
            ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].height = 20

        # Set the column dimensions
        for column in ws.columns:
            ws.column_dimensions[column[0].column_letter].width = 20


        stream = BytesIO()
        wb.save(stream)
        return stream.getvalue()
```

formats.py

```
from import_export.formats.base_formats import XLSX
from tablib.formats import registry


class PrettyXLSX(XLSX):
    TABLIB_MODULE = "prettyxlsx"

    def get_title(self):
        return "Pretty-XLSX"


registry.register("prettyxlsx", "<path>._prettyxlsx.PrettyXLSXFormat")
```

## For admin section

admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    def get_export_formats(self):
        formats = (
            PrettyXLSX,
        )
        return [f for f in formats if f().can_export()]
```

## For views

views.py

```
def bravo_product_export(request):
    dataset = BravoExportResource().export()
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.prettyxlsx,
                            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename=Bravo_Export{datetime.today().strftime("_%d_%m_%Y")}.xlsx'
    return response
```